# XCTest performance metric (i.e. XCTCPUMetric) doesn't give cpu usage in percentage like TimeProfiler in Xcode Instruments

Tags: performance, xctest

Running below XCUITest code, shows result for CPU Time, CPU Cycles and CPU Instructions Retired.
But CPU Time is given in seconds in results report in Xcode. Can anyone help me how can I know the percentage of CPU time is used for app launch using CPU Time in seconds given in results report post running the below test method.

`func testLaunch() throws {`

`let app = XCUIApplication()`
`measure(metrics: [XCTCPUMetric(application: app]){`
`app.launch()`
`}`
`}`

Using Xcode 14.2 to execute Performance Automation test with XCTest framework.